# Bootstrap 4 pin to top navbar element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.1 navbar here. I want my div "#pin_to_top" to be always at the top of the navbar. So that on wider screens it is

### Logo - Menu - "#pin_to_top" (all on the same row)

and on smaller devices it is like

### Logo - "#pin_to_top#

### Menu  (menu is under my logo and div)

Also any other piece of advice about my code would be much appreciated :)

```css
.navbar-brand img {
    height: 2rem;
}

.phonecall {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    background-color: #28a745;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light d-flex flex-column flex-md-row navbar-expand">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <p>LOGO</p>
    </a>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-fill pl-md-5 text-nowrap">
            <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pin_to_top" class="ml-auto d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-self-start" >
        <div class="p-2">
            <a class="">Some info here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-text text-nowrap phonecall px-2">
            <a class="text-white" href="tel:+78005553535">+7-(800)-555-35-35</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 4 includes** a `fixed-top` class to solve your problem. ;)

Comment: doesn't help as far as it break either mobile or desktop version :(

Answer (score 0):

you should give position fix to your class and give this top:0;

Comment: It does nothing iself and if I use 'position' then everything goes broken

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute for parent and add some css for a good design on small screen

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { 
div#pin_to_top {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
}
}
```